# Method to save application settings in delphi

Tags: delphi

I need to save my grid settings like column position and size, form position and size, and also other settings, so that when user reopen form, they will see the same layout.

Right now i save this settings in a string. Something like this

"STOCK_FORM:GRID1:COL1->20;STOCK_FORM:GRID1:COL2->50;"

But this is not easily readable and set. Is there a better way? should i use xml? how's xml performance?

I'm interested to hear how others usually do this.

Thanks in advance.
So sorry for my poor english.

Regards,
Reynaldi

Comment: You can store the columns of a TDBGrid easily into a stream (and restore) http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.DBGrids.TDBGridColumns.SaveToStream

Comment: Part of  [JVCL library](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Component_Overview) are components JvAppStorage, JvFormStorage which offer generic way to make UI persistent.

Comment: @Sir doesn't that save the contents of the grid?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No, it stores the definition of the Colums

Comment: Just do be careful when restoring the form that it will actually display on screen and fit in the available viewport.

Comment: @Sir Rufo: The problem with save to stream is that save all settings and loadstream load all settings. I need it to be flexible, because sometimes i need only the column position, Sometimes the column size, and sometimes both. how about xml? has anyone used that? how is the performance in xml?

Answer (score 0):

You can write the settings out to Ini Files.

[Here](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/tinifile.htm) is an example

Comment: -1: ini files are deprecated and even worse: the example suggest placing the ini file in the application folder (Program Files\MyApp) which means you need admin privs to write there!

Comment: @Remko Can you provide an offical link for "ini files are deprecated"?

Comment: this is more a comment and not an answer

Comment: Ini files were deprecated by the registry. That said, the modern trend for portable apps un-deprecated settings stored in files.

Comment: I just hate the registry. Its one of the worst solutions in the history of OS. Use anything you like (file based) for settings just don't use the registry.

Comment: @Runner what's so bad about the registry?

Comment: Two things especially. First one is that apps are not portable this way or at least not easily and it is very hard if not impossible to find data in registry. I prefer file based settings and other things that the app needs. The other is that it was designer very badly with no clean separation in mind. Everybody, OS and users, just "paint" all over it resulting in a mess that nobody can clean anymore. Noone knows where things are or how to clean orphaned entries. UNIX based system have this solved way better (as many other things) and they just use the file system.

Comment: @David, the problem is that everything the registry was supposed to do, file system does better, maybe the idea behind the registry was good but the real life use and implementation is simply bad. I see I need to write a more in depth article about this even if probably 90% already agree with me :)

Comment: @Runner Are you still using Windows 95? That registry implementation was bad. You try having multiple processes simultaneously updating the same config file and tell me how that works out.

Comment: What you wrote is the problem of design if you ask me. If you update one config file from many processes simultaneously you are using the wrong approach IMHO. Config file is a config file not a database. If you need concurrency you have DBs and they have ACID support. SQLite is more then you will ever need for such cases. Also it is questionable if your design is correct if you have that problem in the first place. What I am talking about is that every application out there and their mothers try to store their junk in the registry. And that does not belong there.

Comment: @Runner So you don't see any need to allow two instances of the same application to run simultaneously?

Comment: Ok you have a point here :) This is a valid and good case that is a plus for the registry.Here it plain and simple wins over lets say an XML file.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This :
   public
     Public declarations }

    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override; // (1)
    procedure BeforeDestruction; override;  // (2) }



   procedure TForm1.BeforeDestruction;
begin
  inherited;
  with TFileStream.Create(PreservePath + ClassName + '.sav',    fmCreate) do
  try
    WriteComponent(Self);
  finally
    Free;
  end; 



   constructor TForm1.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin  
  PreservePath := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 
    'Preserve';
  if not DirectoryExists(PreservePath) then
    CreateDir(PreservePath);
  PreservePath := PreservePath + '\';
  if FileExists(PreservePath + ClassName + '.sav') then
  begin
    CreateNew(AOwner, 0);
    with TFileStream.Create(PreservePath + ClassName + '.sav',
                            fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite) do
    try
      ReadComponent(Self);
    finally
      Free;
    end;
  end
  else
  inherited Create(AOwner);
end;
```

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks for contributing an answer but can you also add an explanation on how your code solves the problem?

Comment: Is it solved your issue ! if its so , please mark the answer as a solution ..& I will explain the code .